# Combine string and OBJECT ID using VB

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table, vb

I am trying to update the FACILITYID field with a String "SWW" and then follow the "SWW" with the OBJECTID field.

So I will end up with SSW1", "SSW2" all the way to the end in the FACILITYID field.

I know for python it is simply: "SWW" + str(!OBJECTID!)

How would you do this using VB in field calculator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The visual basic code would be:

[Field Name1] & " " & [Field Name2] & " " & [Field Name3]

If you didn't want spaces in between, just ignore the " " part in the middle and do:

[Field Name1] & [Field Name2]